# disk2vhd64 - Copying volume with boot information via command line

Tags: vhdx, disk2vhd

I'm having a problem creating a vhdx file using disk2vhd64 in command line. I don't know how to add \?\Volume{...} to vhdx file since drives can be specified like c: or so. I'm using this manual https://adamtheautomator.com/disk2vhd/ . Tried to search web for solution, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Why don’t you use the utility GUI?

Comment: Have you tried **disk2vhd -c “\?\Volume{...}” "\\file-server\Backups\snapshot-$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd).vhd"**? But if you want the virtual drive within the VM to be bootable you should include all relevant partitions on the disk.

Comment: I want to create a scheduled event so my server will backup onto another machine, in event of failure I can start a VM right away. Don't want to do backup by myself. Tried line you mentioned and it doesn't work. I can use * to copy all partitions, but I don't want to backup volume with archive data, just work volumes I need the most.

Comment: That particular volume is the system reserved partition and shouldn’t be necessary for what you’re doing.  What error did you receive? What did you try exactly? I didn’t have the entire volume identifier so I couldn’t suggest the complete command

Comment: When I just copy C: and E: volumes Hyper-V can't boot VM. System reserved volume is necessary for it to run in Hyper-V. Volume displayed in GUI is **\\?\Volume{1ac006ea-4520-11eb-93e7-806e6f6e6963}** . Using **"C:\Program Files\disk2vhd64.exe" disk2vhd c: e: "\\share\d\VM\myvmname-%date%.vhdx"** line in bat file works just fine, just need this additional volume.

Comment: Is the host volume MBR or GPT? I suppose it does not matter.  If you could mount the virtual disk, which I don't suggest, you could in theory recreate the system reserved partition through a secondary process. What you might have to do, in order to accomplish what you want, is assign a disk letter to that volume. The tool might not be smart enough to accomplish your goal without it.

Comment: Volume is MBR style. I'm affraid it's so simple it can't replicate drives without letter. Too bad.

Comment: In another manual it clearly says all drives must be copied using * to add System Reserved volumes. https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/using-disk2vhd-for-physical-to-virtual-conversions-p2v/

Comment: I still suspect if you were to assign a disk letter to that partition you could accomplish your goal, should be a relatively easy chore, to automate by using disk part to assign and unassign the drive letter